# Using python asyncio with subprocesses

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

In python, I have a run method that uses asyncio. This process creates child processes which also use asyncio. It appears that new subprocesses created after my parent process inherit the event loop of the parent process. Is there any way around this? The new subprocess will have a running event loop which I can't stop. I tried `new_event_loop()` but this doesn't really address the clean up issues with the old event loop.

somewhat related:
https://bugs.python.org/issue22087

Comment: How exactly are you starting the child processes?

Comment: I am using the multiprocessing library's 'fork' method. multiprocess.Process(target=myFunc, args=(args, port,))

Comment: Try calling `multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')` immediately after `import multiprocessing`.